# Divide spacing in bootstrap group of buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to get equal spacing in this group of buttons?
When I add `pull-right` to the class the search and plus buttons is set to below the search box.

[image]

```
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-3">
                  <small>Firma</small>
                  <a href="?sort_name=klantnaam&sort=asc" title="'.$lang['sorteer_asc'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet glyph_sorting" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                  <a href="?sort_name=klantnaam&sort=desc" title="'.$lang['sorteer_asc'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt glyph_sorting" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                  </th>
                  <th class="col-md-3"><small>Plaats</small></th>
                  <th class="col-md-3"><small>Telefoon</small></th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">
                      <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                      </form>
                  </th>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I think your `<div class="form-group col-xs-8">` is playing with you. Try to put the other 2 buttns in it.

Comment: That is setting the search and plus buttons to below the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit based on comment:**

1. Set parent container (`form`) to flexbox row, and center it's children elements horizontally with even space in-between with `justify-content:space-between` & vertically with `align-items:center`.
2. Override bootstrap's `.form-control`'s `padding` & `margin`, which is whats causing the space async between `button`s & the search `input`.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

div.form-group {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="col-md-3">
      <small>Firma</small>
      <a href="?sort_name=klantnaam&sort=asc" title="'.$lang['sorteer_asc'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet glyph_sorting" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <a href="?sort_name=klantnaam&sort=desc" title="'.$lang['sorteer_asc'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt glyph_sorting" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </th>
    <th class="col-md-3"><small>Plaats</small></th>
    <th class="col-md-3"><small>Telefoon</small></th>
    <th class="col-md-3">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </form>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In the picture is shown what I have now, there is some extra space between the search box and search button.

Comment: Muiter, better now?

Comment: Sure, added it above. Regards.